# Could not find method: Process. (My implementation of FilterUrlExtensions)

Tags: pipelines

I'm using Sitecore 9.0.2.

I am implementing a class to override Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest.FilterUrlExtensions.

I wrote my patch config as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <initialize>
        <processor type="eSundhedWeb.Foundation.Permissions.Pipelines.CustomPreprocessor, eSundhedWeb.Foundation.Permissions" patch:instead="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest.FilterUrlExtensions, Sitecore.Kernel']">
          <param desc="Allowed extensions (comma separated)">aspx, ashx, asmx</param>
          <param desc="Blocked extensions (comma separated)">*</param>
          <param desc="Blocked extensions that stream files (comma separated)">*</param>
          <param desc="Blocked extensions that do not stream files (comma separated)"/>
        </processor>
      </initialize>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

As I'm trying to run it I get the following exception:

```
Could not find method: Process. Pipeline: /sitecore[database="SqlServer" xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/"]/pipelines/initialize/processor[type="eSundhedWeb.Foundation.Permissions.Pipelines.CustomPreprocessor, eSundhedWeb.Foundation.Permissions" patch:source="Foundation.Permissions.CustomPreprocessor.config"]
```

I've verified that my method signature matches the signature in FilterUrlExtensions as you can see here:

My class:

```
 public class CustomPreprocessor : Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest.FilterUrlExtensions

    { 
        public CustomPreprocessor(string allowed, string blocked, string streamFiles, string doNotStreamFiles) : base(allowed, blocked, streamFiles, doNotStreamFiles)
        {
        }

        public override void Process(PreprocessRequestArgs args)
        {

            base.Process(args);
        }

    }
```

FilterUrlExtensions:

```
    public class FilterUrlExtensions : PreprocessRequestProcessor
    {
        public FilterUrlExtensions(string allowed, string blocked, string streamFiles, string doNotStreamFiles);

        public override void Process(PreprocessRequestArgs args);
    }
```

What might be causing this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You implemented custom `preprocessRequest` processor but then you regisitered it in `initialize` pipeline.

Change your configuration to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <preprocessRequest>
        <processor type="eSundhedWeb.Foundation.Permissions.Pipelines.CustomPreprocessor, eSundhedWeb.Foundation.Permissions" patch:instead="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest.FilterUrlExtensions, Sitecore.Kernel']">
          <param desc="Allowed extensions (comma separated)">aspx, ashx, asmx</param>
          <param desc="Blocked extensions (comma separated)">*</param>
          <param desc="Blocked extensions that stream files (comma separated)">*</param>
          <param desc="Blocked extensions that do not stream files (comma separated)"/>
        </processor>
      </preprocessRequest>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```